# the simplest way to play two sounds at the same time (c++ winapi)

Tags: c++, winapi

Can somebody help me with making simple win32 gui application (i'm using code::blocks) in which I can play two sounds at the same time. When message loop receives WM_CREATE i want to start playing music.wav, and everytime user clicks window (WM_LBUTTONDOWN) i want to play click.wav (without interrupting music.wav). I searched for it and I found that it can be done with directsound (directx), but it was too complicated because it has a lot of more functions. Is it possible to do it in more simple way (something like playsound api function or something - I know it can not play two sounds at the same time, but is there anything similar). And if possible, I would like to play wave files from resources.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need a library that supports mixing.  Like DirectSound.  There are a lot of them, you'll need to go shopping.

Comment: yeah, i know i will need directsound, but is there any simple way to just play two sounds using it (i dont need any effects and so on)... and i would like to play sounds from resources

Comment: I found solution: libZPlay is good enough for my project. It can not play wave from resources, so I'm wondering if there is any way to get resource file "path", or copy file from resources to disk?

Answer (score 0):

You could use XAudio2, as DirectSound is deprecated.

[XAudio2 Introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Read the "Getting Started" section, there are sample code for reading and playing audio. You just need to create a "mastering voice" and add some sound sources.